# Using a Table Valued Function inside a Recursive CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions, recursive-cte

I am trying to use a recursive CTE to combine multiple calls to a table valued function.

I have a fiddle at: https://dbfiddle.uk/kktqHivz

I have a table called `sales`:

```
create table sales (
    date date,
    total decimal(6,2)
);
```

The function `ds(date)` selects all the sales for a date:

```sql
create function ds(@date date) returns table as
return select date, total from sales where date=@date;
```

I thought I could put them into a recursive CTE as follows:

```sql
with cte as (
    select cast('2023-01-01' as date) as n, *
    from ds('2023-01-01')
    union all
    select dateadd(day,1,n),d.*
    from cte, ds(n) as d    --  can’t use ds(n) or ds(cte.n)
    where n<'2023-01-05'
)
select * from cte order by n option(maxrecursion 100);
```

but the message I get is:

> Invalid column name 'n'

I’m stuck at this point. The `n` is a column from the CTE, and normally you can us it in the recursive member, as you see with the `SELECT` clause. Somehow I can’t use it as an argument for the `ds()` TVF.

Is there a way I can use the generated date `n` in the table valued function?

Comment: I am confused as to why you would need a recursive CTE for this (unless this example is just much, much less complicated than what you're actually trying to achieve here). Why not just `select [date], total from sales where [date] >= '20230101' and date < '20230105';`?

Comment: @ZLK This is a trivial example, I know, but I wanted to see whether it’s possible to incorporate a TVF in a CTE.

Comment: You can - you have an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by the other answer, you would need `cross apply`.

But the logic of your CTE is incorrect. You need to generate the dates first, then `apply` the function

```sql
with cte as (
    select cast('2023-01-01' as date) as n

    union all

    select dateadd(day, 1, n)
    from cte
    where n < '2023-01-05'
)
select *
from cte
cross apply ds(cte.n)
order by n
option(maxrecursion 100);
```

Having said that, you should probably just use a straight range lookup

```sql
select
  date,
  total
from sales
where date >= @date
  and date < '2023-01-05';
```

Comment: This looks right: I have just tried it on the fiddle and it gives me there results I was looking for. I first thought of doing something similar, but I didn’t use a `cross apply` which solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Apropos the simpler option, that’s not available in the real data which is too heavily wrapped in everything else including TVFs. I just needed to build the trivial sample to test the method.

Comment: BTW this is also a helpful example of `CROSS APPLY`.

Answer (score 0):

This `from cte, ds(n) as d` is an old style comma join, so of course `ds` cannot reference a column in the cte. Instead try a `cross apply` which is the equivalent of a join for functions that require values from the base table.

```
with cte as (
    select cast('2023-01-01' as date) as n, *
    from ds('2023-01-01')
    union all
    select dateadd(day,1,n), d.*
    from cte
    cross apply ds(n) as d
    where n < '2023-01-05'
)
select *
from cte
order by n
option(maxrecursion 100);
```

Comment: That’s giving me too many rows. I think it’s cross joining all of the data.

Comment: Yip, thats how cross apply works - what do you want it to do? Your original query attempts to do the same thing as you have no join condition either.

Comment: @DaleK, that's because his function returns more than one row, so cte becomes multi-rowed and multiplies itself further :D

Comment: @Manngo, i think it's better if you just generate a list of dates in a CTE, and then join them in one call against ds function